# React Routes is not working React Router dom

Tags: reactjs

Route is not working i am a beginner of react.when i type the urls on the browser text is not displaying.what i tried so far i attached the below. i created the pages inside pages folder.

```
import Index from "./pages/Index";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Product from "./pages/Product";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import {BrowserRouter,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
   <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
         
          <Route path = "/">
            <Index/>
          </Route>

          <Route path = "/login">
            <Login/>
          </Route>

          <Route path = "/product">
            <Product/>
          </Route>

          <Route path = "/register">
            <Register/>
          </Route>
      
      </BrowserRouter>

   </div> 
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap all your routes inside **Routes** component. It's part of the react-router-dom

```html
import Index from "./pages/Index";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Product from "./pages/Product";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path = "/" element={<Index />} />
          <Route path = "/login" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path = "/product" element={<Product />} />
          <Route path = "/register" element={<Register/>} />
        </Routes>
       </BrowserRouter>
     </div> 
 )}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks a lotttttttttttttttttttttttyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all route in routes like this

```
function App() {

  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Index/>} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>} />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Route shows the element you specify in its props using the `element` prop.

Try this:

```
import Index from "./pages/Index";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Product from "./pages/Product";
import Register from "./pages/Register";
import {BrowserRouter,Route} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
   <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path='/'>
            <Route index element={<Index/>} />
            <Route path="login" element={<Login/>} />
            <Route path="product" element={<Product/>} />
            <Route path="register" element={<Register/>} />
          </Route>
      </BrowserRouter>
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Extra context:

What this does is that you specify a home route at the path `/` and all other routes are children of this home route.

The index property in the first nested route is used to tell the program this is the index page of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass the element prop where the path should direct to in the Routes tag. You can find documentation [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes).

This should work:

```
<Route index element={<Index/>}/>
<Route path="login" element={<Login/>}/>
<Route path="product" element={<Product/>}/>
<Route path="register" element={<Register/>}/>
```